# Show attribute's image instead of label in the admin page

Tags: image, magento, attributes, label, admin

I'm wondering if is it possible to show images instead of labels for the specific/all attributes in the Magento backend (where you edit/add your products), please share with me if you know how to done this.
Thank you

*Example:
Show the red image instead of Red label when you want to select the color for your product, no matter if it is an Multiple-Select Attribute or an Dropdown Attribute.*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: https://youtu.be/BLikP6BDH5w

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Just because one possible answer to a question is about programming it doesn't make the question programming-related. Show the code, tell us what it isn't doing for you and what it should - then we can help fix the code.